# Found picture, want to know more about. It

Tags: united-states

[image]

...this picture looks like an important United Nations meetings, however, everything is covered, or papers flipped over, which makes me think it secretive

Comment: Hi & welcome to Genealogy & Family History SE. What is the provenance of the picture and how does it relate to genealogy? Everyone is wearing a uniform and there is a visitors gallery -- it seems more like a tribunal (war crimes?) than a United Nations session.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion of picture, and I truly didn't realize this wonderful site was strictly geneology/family history, I just figured military....that someone may know something about this picture.....you do wonderful things for people...GOD BLESS.... THANK YOU ALL FOR YOUR SERVICE....

Comment: Photo identification and historical background do get covered here but there "should" be a connection to family history -- whether a relative was involved in the depicted event or some other link. The question could be migrated to History SE, but that is the moderators' call.

Comment: I agree that if there is no family history connection, this should be closed or migrated. I've flagged the Q so the other mods will be alerted.

Comment: P.S. Hi, Lisa, and welcome!  How can we help you with your family history?

Comment: And the giant snow globe in the top right corner?

Comment: The bald guy facing away from the camera looks to be a British Brigadier judging by his shoulder rank insignia. The chap with the glasses might be American judging by the uniform. And I think there maybe Japanese Navy officers, but not sure. The white armbands probably mean some kind of duty officer, or guard, or assistant to the flag senior officers.

Comment: Do you have any other context - where was the picture found and do you have more or possibly related papers/letters?

Comment: Chap at the back right has Navy lieutenant insignia on his sleeve - could be RN or USN.

Comment: There seems to be a girl at top right holding a heart with some writing on it.

Comment: This could quite possibly be from the international military tribunal far east into Japanese war crimes in 1947. Or a number of any of the other trials.

I don't think it's especially secretive judging from all the onlookers in the windows.

Answer (score 9):

I do believe the location, and this is my best guess, is the Military Armistice Building in South Korea.

Exactly which armistice meeting (they've had quite a few now) it is, I am not sure. But it does look quite similar to the room in the photos. I cannot be certain though.

[[image: Military Armistice Commission Building]

[[image: 1968 Military Commission]

[[image: Another angle]